# What is the recommended upgrade path for the obsolete FindServicePoint method?

Tags: .net

I'm working on some legacy code that contains this:

```cs
ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(myServiceUrl)).ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 60 * 1000;
```

When I found the docs for the [`FindServicePoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager?view=net-7.0#methods) method it says it's obsolete. There is a remark in that same doc that says to use `HttpClient` instead of `ServicePointManager`.

I can see that `HttpClient` has some time out properties, but I'm not sure which one replaces the functionality of `ConnectionLeaseTimeout`.

How can I implement what setting the `ConnectionLeaseTimeout` property is currently doing using the `HttpClient` class?

**Update 1**
The [`SocketsHttpHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.socketshttphandler?view=net-7.0) appears to be the replacement class. An instance of this class can be passed to the constructor of the `HttpClient` client.

There are bunch of properties that can be set on `SocketsHttpHandler` but not `ConnectionLeaseTimeout` . I'll still have to figure out which `SocketsHttpHandler` property or properties are a suitable replacment.